# How can I find what parameters are passed to the event methods of Shell.Explorer?

Tags: activex, webbrowser-control, autohotkey

I thought Shell.Explorer means Webbrowser Control in AutoHotkey.

But as I view the output of the parameters of the`NavigateError` event, it is slightly different than the ones described in MSDN pages.

I found two different pages at MSDN for `NavigateError`.

- DWebBrowserEvents2::NavigateError http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- NavigateError Event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268221%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Since the second parameter shows a url with the below code, I guess AutoHotkey is using the DwebBrowserEvents2 interface but the MSDN page says the method accepts 5 parameters while AutoHotkey receives 6 of them.

```
new WBConttrol("file:///" A_ScriptDir "/nofile")
class WBConttrol {
    NavigateError(oParams*) {
        msgbox, 64, % Parameters, % "the number of passed parameters: " oParams.MaxIndex() "`n"
            . "1: " (IsObject(oParams.1) ? "object" : oParams.1) "`n"
            . "2: " (IsObject(oParams.2) ? "object" : oParams.2) "`n"       ; url
            . "3: " (IsObject(oParams.3) ? "object" : oParams.3) "`n"
            . "4: " (IsObject(oParams.4) ? "object" : oParams.4) "`n"
            . "5: " (IsObject(oParams.5) ? "object" : oParams.5) "`n"
            . "6: " (IsObject(oParams.6) ? "object" : oParams.6) "`n"
    }       
    __New(strURL="") {
        static WB
        Gui, New, Resize MaximizeBox
        Gui, Add, ActiveX, vWB w300 h200, Shell.Explorer  
        Gui, show, w300 h200
        ComObjConnect(WB, this)
        WB.Navigate(strURL)
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Shell.Explorer` does indeed mean the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752085.aspx) control.

The extra (sixth) parameter is defined in the documentation for [ComObjConnect()](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/ComObjConnect.htm):

> PrefixEventName([Params..., **ComObject**])
>   ...
>   *ComObject* is optional, and can only be used if the correct number of Params are defined; it contains a reference to the original wrapper object which was passed to ComObjConnect.

The reason for this extra parameter is that some COM event methods do not define any parameters at all, and therefore don't provide a reference to the COM object which the event is being raised on.